# How to show a presentModalView inside another presentModalView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

How do I show a presentModalView inside another presentModalView?

I wanna call this:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(settingsTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

IN HERE

```
UINavigationController *_nc = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:scannerVC] autorelease]; //Put our SKScannerViewController into a UINavigationController. (So it looks nice).
        [scannerVC release];

[self presentModalViewController:_nc animated:YES]; //Slide it up onto the screen.
```

then

```
//another screen pop up in _nc
qrcode_info *otherVC = [[qrcode_info alloc] initWithNibName:@"qrcode_info" bundle:Nil  ];

//  [self presentModalViewController: otherVC animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `-presentModalViewController:animated:` from within the view controller that is being shown modally.

Comment: i wanna call this.
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(settingsTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UINavigationController *_nc = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:scannerVC] autorelease];